# own automatically defined data type in Python

Tags: python

Let's say I have following code:

```
mystring='abcd'
print(type(mystring))
```

Python understands that `mystring` is a string object and returns `<class 'str'>`. How does this happen?
What if I want to declare my own data type that supports the same logic, that is when I type `print(type(mystring))` I receive `<class 'myClass'>`, not python default class `<class 'str'>`. How can I achieve that?

**Update:** I am interested in how to rearrange the logic of class auto-definition? I don't want to declare variable explicitly as an object of myClass by `myString = myClass('abcd')`. I just want to type `myString = 'abcd'` and be sure that Python has defined `myString` as instance of `myClass`. Is that possible? May be it is all about inheritance/overriding str class?

Comment: What do you mean, how does this happen? You have a string and you got its type, and its type is `str`, what else would happen?

Comment: To define a custom type you define a *class*. Indeed, "class" and "type" in python *are synonymous*. Indeed, `type` is *just a class*, the class of *all classes*, i.e. a *metaclass* if you want to know a little more about how it all works

Comment: Beside the point, but [class names should be ***Upper**CamelCase*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names), so, `MyClass`.

Comment: `'abcd'` is always in instance of `str`, you can't make it something else without being explicit about it.

Comment: For reference: [Lexical analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html) > [Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) > [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you want to do. How [literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) are defined in Python is inherent to the language. You can definitely override `str` which will change what happens when it's actually used, but this isn't recommended.

If you could globally overwrite the inherent primitive types of the language how would you expect other packages to behave?

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self, string):
...         self.strlen = len(string)
...

>>> str = MyClass

>>> type("foo")
str

>>> type(MyClass("foo"))
__main__.MyClass

>>> type(str("foo"))
__main__.MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about Object Oriented Programming in python. You can make your own custom class with specific functions.

For example:

```
class myClass(str):
    pass

myString = myClass('abcd')
print(type(myString))
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.myClass'>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my question concerns a little bit different issue: I am interested in how to rearrange the logic of class auto-definition? I don't want to declare variable explicitly as an object of myClass by `myString = myClass('abcd')`. I just want to type `myString = 'abcd'` and be sure that Python has defined `myString` as instance of myClass. Is that possible? May be it is all about inheritance/overrideinf str class?

Comment: @KiNest what you are asking for doesn't make any sense. Python doesn't have "class auto-definition". You *create objects* in Python, and any object *has a type*. `myString = myClass('abcd')` is **not** a declaration, **python doesn't have variable declarations**.

Comment: @KiNest and note, you probably almost certainly do not want to inherit from `str`. Maybe, but I suspect not